# React Dependency Upgrade - Is there any practice which we should follow to upgrade the dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, webpack, dependencies

Here are the list of dependencies and devDependencies which are required to be updated they are pretty old some are already deprecated.

```
"dependencies": 
    "axios": "0.16.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.17",
    "express": "4.15.3",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "firebase": "8.3.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "has-flag": "2.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "prop-types": "15.5.8",
    "qrcode.react": "^0.9.3",
    "react": "15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.31.0",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "5.1.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "4.1.2",
    "react-dom": "15.5.4",
    "react-fontawesome": "1.6.1",
    "react-google-maps": "8.3.3",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router": "4.1.1",
    "react-router-config": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "react-slick": "0.22.2",
    "recharts": "1.1.0",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "0.5.12",
    "slick-carousel": "1.6.0",
    "webpack": "2.6.1",
    "yaml-loader": "0.4.0"

"devDependencies": 
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.1",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bourbon": "4.3.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "fileloader": "2.0.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "material-design-lite": "1.3.0",
    "node-bourbon": "4.2.8",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.5",
    "style-loader": "0.17.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-browser-plugin": "1.0.20",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.5",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "0.11.0"
```

I tried upgrading the node version to the latest and tried installing the dependencies it is breaking with node-sass and one thing leading to upgrade another and it goes on...
Do I need to go through each and every dependency and convert the code accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to upgrade the versions of the dependencies in your project.

```
 npm audit fix
```

This command upgrades all dependencies to latest version.
So you should check whether other dependencies are matched with upgraded node version.